# Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.10 my PC is starting by itself

Tags: boot

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.10 my PC is starting by itself. After 10 or so minutes working on the PC the lockscreen appears

I set the Power Settings to "nothing", but that didn't help.  The motherboard is an Asus Strix H370-F gaming.

Comment: There's nothing in Ubuntu that can turn your PC on if it's off unless you've set up some kind of Wake on LAN.

Comment: Thanks Nmath.No wake on lan. Can't get into my BIOS.PC started even with cable disconnected. Happenly since yesterday no more starting by its own.

Comment: Lowie:it was not a software problem but a hardware. It was the power unit. The first thing my computerexpert sad when i contacted him was:"the problem lies in the power unit". Strangely enough nobody mentions that on the internet.

Comment: @Lowie When you see this, would you consider moving that info to an answer?  This could be useful information to others.  See my answer below, but let me know if you'd like to do one on your own, and I'll delete mine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*<sub><sup>Note:</sup> This is information from the OP's comments above that makes (IMHO) a useful answer for others.  @Lowie:  If you would like to copy this to your own answer, please do so.  Then flag this one for a Mod to delete.</sub>*

This turned out to be a hardware issue.  The Power Supply was faulty, and replacing it solved the problem.  Thanks to the OP's computer expert for suggesting this was the probably cause.

The fact that it started occurring after upgrading to 22.10 seems like it may have been coincidental, and certainly made both the OP and the community here on Ask Ubuntu incorrectly consider *software* causes.